# window.parent.frames['id'] vs window.parent.frames[0]

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

I have a set of sibling IFrames on a page, and want to communicate via `postMessage` between them. (They are all on the same origin, but the parent page is not).

I want to get a reference to other siblings frames from inside a frame. The way to this seems to call `window.parent.frames` since it does not trigger a cross origin error on read.

Ideally I would like to use it this way: `window.parent.frames['someFrameId']` However, on chrome at least, I get blocked from doing so:

`window.parent.frames['frame-id']`

> VM11236:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://myframedomain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)

If I get it by index instead, by looping through everything in window.parent.frames, it doenst trigger the exception.

I'm trying to find out why, because I've seen other integrations use it the way I want to use it before.

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering, I believe I found out why. It seems to you need to name your windows correctly to use it this way.

`window.name = 'my-frame'`

`window.parent.frames['my-frame']`

> works

`window.name = undefined;

`window.parent.frames['my-frame']`

> Uncaught DOMException